# I can not change the analyzer and mapping at already existing index

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like change settings and mapping on an already existing index in elasticsearch. However, I get the error.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/myindex/_close
```

> {"acknowledged":true}

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/myindex/_settings -d '{
 "index": {
   "analysis": {
     "analyzer": {
      "custom_analyzer": {
       "type": "custom",
       "tokenizer": "keyword",
       "filter": ["lowercase"]
      }
     }
    }
   }
 }'
```

> {"acknowledged":true}

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_mapping -d '{
 "properties": {
  "myfield": {
       "type": "string",
       "search_analyzer": "custom_analyzer",
       "index_analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
  }
 }
}'
```

> {"error":"MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [myfield] has different index_analyzer]}]","status":400}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could always add a mapping if a new field is introduced in the existing type. For a better approach you could transfer the data of one index type to another new type with modified mapping.

Comment: I understand, mandatory to reindex for what I want.

Answer (score 0):

All indices are stored immutable so you have to reindex you data.

**zero downtime ver. 1**

To reindex you can follow this steps:

- create index with wanted settings/mappings
- pull you data from old to new index with the _bulk API

**zero downtime ver. 2**

Or you can create a new index with wanted settings/mappings and create a alias (with the old index name) to the newly created index.

**downtime needed**

The last way to do this is to close your index, make your changes and reopen your index again.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I get the error when I set settings after the index close.